# How to use a string to specify class for variable declaration in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, variable-declaration

I am trying to use a string that is passed into a method to cast the objects in an array to that type and iterate over them.

My code looks like this:

```
- (NSArray *)serializableEntities:(NSArray *)entities forEntityName:(NSString *)entityName
{
    NSMutableArray *seriazliedEntities = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i=0; i < [entities count]; i++) {

        entityName *entityObj = (entityName *) [entities objectAtIndex:i];

        ...
    }
}
```

How can I do this? Is this possible?

I have tried doing it like so but believe I am missing the correct method/syntax:

```
Class objectClass = NSClassFromString(entityName);
objectClass *myObject = (objectClass *) [entities objectAtIndex:i];
```

Comment: Why do you need to cast that objects? What do you do inside the loop?

Comment: You can only cast to a *type*, not to a *class object*. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Have a look at `NSCoder`, it may serve your needs.

Comment: Agree with Martin. Also, since your `entityName` is a run-time value and variable types are pretty much a purely compile-time thing which don't survive into the binary, what you're trying to do is meaningless. Just use `id` as the type.

Comment: Thanks @SviatoslavYakymiv. I removed the casting. It was unneeded.

Answer (score 3):

(From my and Ken's comment:) That is not possible. You can only cast to a *type* (which is something known at compile-time). You can use the generic Objective-C type `id`:

```
id entityObj = [entities objectAtIndex:i];
```

If all objects have a common superclass, use that:

```
SuperClass *entityObj = [entities objectAtIndex:i];
```

or perhaps all objects conform to a common protocol:

```
id<CommonProtocol> entityObj = [entities objectAtIndex:i];
```

Of course you can *check* the actual class of the object at runtime, for example

```
id entityObj = [entities objectAtIndex:i];
if ([entityObj isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(entityName)]) {

}
```

Comment: You're right. I've removed the casting as it was not needed. I was trying to iterate over NSManagedObject subclasses (different objects used in the app) and generate JSONserialized versions of key/value pairs that were not null. I've come up with the solution, posted below.

Comment: @MAzam: I do not see a solution posted by you. - I have tried to answer your question as good as possible with the provided information. If all objects are NSManagedObject subclasses, you can use `NSManagedObject *entityObj = ...`, as suggested above. - If your problem is solved, you should either accept an answer or post+accept your own answer.

Comment: Got distracted with family stuff. Solution is posted now.

Answer (score 0):

The key was to using the superclass of the `NSManagedObject` subclasses rather than trying to determine the actual subclass. This allowed me to remove the code trying to figure out what class it was. Here is the working solution:

```
- (NSArray *)serializableEntities:(NSArray *)entities
{
    NSMutableArray *seriazliedEntities = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i=0; i < [entities count]; i++) {

        NSManagedObject *entityObj = [entities objectAtIndex:i];

        NSMutableDictionary *serializedEntity = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        for (NSString *key in [[entityObj entity] attributesByName]) {
            if ([entityObj valueForKey:key]) [serializedEntity setValue:[self nullCheck:[entityObj valueForKey:key]] forKey:key];
        }

        [seriazliedEntities addObject:serializedEntity];
    }

    return seriazliedEntities;
}
```

Comment: To remove the question from the "unanswered" list, you should "accept" one of the answers by clicking on the check mark.